# Get data from 2 differents days and compare

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question. So I have this data in array :

```
id      idm         amount           date
1        5          10              2017-08-23 12:12:12
2        5          20              2017-08-23 12:14:16
3        6          13              2017-08-23 18:00:00
4        5          25              2017-08-24 19:00:00
5        5          160             2017-08-24 19:30:00
```

So the idea is to get the sum of amount from date `2017-08-23` and compare with date `2017-08-24`. If difference between those 2 values for a user is bigger than 20 for example in this case I found a user.

My propose was to make 2 sql's :

```
select sum(amount) as previous_amount, idm 
FROM table
WHERE date >= '2017-08-23 00:00:00' AND date <= '2017-08-23 23:59:59' 
GROUP By idm

select sum(amount) as actual_amount, idm 
FROM table
WHERE date >= '2017-08-24 00:00:00' AND date <= '2017-08-24 23:59:59' 
GROUP By idm
```

And make the treatment in php, but maybe exist a methode to do that in sql. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: what is expected output from your sample data?

Comment: `idm`    `difference` if is bigger than 20

Comment: Is the 20 difference per `idm`? Could you show expected  result? (ie for `idm=6` there is only 1 entry and thus you expect no difference?)

Comment: Yes @urban difference per idm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, this is what you want:

```
select 
idm,
sum(case when date >= '2017-08-23 00:00:00' AND date <= '2017-08-23 23:59:59' then amount end)  -
sum(case when date >= '2017-08-24 00:00:00' AND date <= '2017-08-24 23:59:59' then amount end)  as diff
from your_table
group by idm
having diff not between -20 and 20
```

Comment: Could we get only users that have data in both dates, I mean if user have amount on 2017-08-23 and on 2017-08-24 so we get this user otherwise no

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but this might work..

```
select (sum(b.amount) - sum(a.amount)) as result, idm
from table a join table b on a.idm = b.idm
where a.date = date('2017-08-23') and b.date = date('2017-08-24')
group by idm
```

if you can provide a fiddle that might help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to calculate the differences per `idm` and `day` (which I 'll show you how) and do the rest in the code. So looking at this first part, I am using the `datetime` manipulation functions to remove the time element out of the datetime values which keeps date only as string. This is now something we can group on:

```
select sum(amount) as previous_amount, idm, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') as day 
FROM test
GROUP By idm, day
order by idm, day
```

This will give you something like:

```
previous_amount idm day
30              5   2017-08-23
185             5   2017-08-24
13              6   2017-08-23
```

At this point I would continue in code. However, if you want to do this in the database you need to join the above result table on itself. This simulates a LAG/LEAD behavior (two Oracle instructions that are not available in MySQL).  So the query is:

```
select 
    diff1.idm, 
    previous_amount, 
    actual_amount, 
    diff2.actual_amount-diff1.previous_amount as difference, 
    diff1.day as from_day, 
    diff2.day as to_day
from (
  select sum(amount) as previous_amount, idm, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') as day 
  FROM test
  GROUP By idm, day
  order by idm, day
) as diff1
left join (
  select sum(amount) as actual_amount, idm, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') as day 
  FROM test
  GROUP By idm, day
  order by idm, day
) as diff2 on diff1.idm=diff2.idm
where DATE(diff2.day) > DATE(diff1.day) 
  and diff2.actual_amount-diff1.previous_amount > 20;
```

The result of the above looks like:

```
idm previous_amount actual_amount   difference  from_day    to_day
5   30              185             155         2017-08-23  2017-08-24
```

Note that the above query guarantees that day2 > day1 but does not enforce *one day only* difference. However, I think it could get extended to do so fairly easily.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08b3a/23) here

UPDATE #1

If you want to guarantee single day difference then replace the `where` condition with `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, diff1.day, diff2.day) = 1` [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e9efe/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try that, should be faster than @Shuddh solution because it does not rely on a join

```
SELECT 
  idm,
  sum(IF(date(`date`) = '2017-08-23', amount, 0)) as amountDay1,
  sum(IF(date(`date`) = '2017-08-24', amount, 0)) as amountDay1,

  sum(IF(date(`date`) = '2017-08-23', amount, 0)) 
  - sum(IF(date(`date`) = '2017-08-24', amount, 0)) as diffDay1Day2
FROM 
  table
GROUP BY
  idm
```

Comment: This just gives you a hint to set you on the right direction. You can find your own solution with that

Comment: @Benvorth I used join so that there might ignore case where idm exist only on any one of the dates.